# Multiplying each column in matrix by the corresponding row in a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

I have a 6231x16825 matrix `H` and a 16825x1 column vector `W`.

For example, if `W = [2; 3; 3 ...]'`  and `H = [1 2 3; 4 5 6 ...]`, I need to obtain:

```
prod = [1*2 2*3 3*3; 4*2 5*3 6*3]
```

How to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways possible, choose the one that fits you:

- Using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

  ```
  res = bsxfun(@times, H, W(:).');
  ```
- Matrix multiplication:

  ```
  res = diag(W) * H;
  ```
- A loop:

  ```
   res = nan(size(H));
   for k = 1:size(H,2)
       res(:, k)= W .* H(:, k);
   end
  ```

Comment: +1 as well, but it would be better to use another name for the result (`prod` is a builtin function)

Comment: @EitanT and to think that you closed my `bsxfun` fun question... No hard feelings ;-)